# res.location is not setting page url in express (MEAN stack)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, mean-stack

I require a hard coded password protected page. I used href to redirect to a page as /admin/user/password:

```
    <a ng-href="/admin/{{user}}/{{password}}" class="form-control btn btn-primary" >Submit</a>
```

I am using angular $scope.user and $scope.password as my ng-models for input fields. This request is caught by Express route.get function:

```
    app.route('/admin/:user/:password')
     .get(admin.renderAdmin);
```

Below is my admin.renderAdmin Page :

```
exports.renderAdmin = function (req, res) {
console.log("Requested with username and password");

if (req.params.user === "*******" && req.params.password === "******") {

    res.location('/admin');
    res.render('admin');

} else {
    res.send(null);
}
};
```

/admin is the url that i require and admin.ejs stores the html that i want to render on this url.

The output that i am getting is the page renders the admin.ejs but the url is not changing and it is the same as href.

Kindly help me on what i might be doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try render with a callback?

```
// if a callback is specified, the rendered HTML string has to be sent explicitly
res.render('admin', function(err, html) {
  res.location('/admin');
  res.send(html);
});
```

Also, if you want the page to actually change, you should use `res.redirect()` as opposed to `res.location()`.